# Mismatch between preview content and saved content wrt newline separator

Tags: bug, markdown-rendering

**How to reproduce:**
Edit or create a new answer, paste two links, use `\` between them so they show in different lines. Like this:

```
https://flathub.org/apps/details/net.sourceforge.Pdfedit\
https://flathub.org/apps/details/com.itextpdf.RUPS
```

> [image]

**What happens:**
Preview correctly shows each link in its own line. But after saving the answer then both of them are shown on the same line.

> [image]

**What is expected:**
Saved content should look the same as previewed content.

**How to workaround bug:**
It seems we need to insert a space between first link and `\` so it works as expected and saved content correctly shows each link on its own line (as the preview does). Like this:

```
https://flathub.org/apps/details/net.sourceforge.Pdfedit \
https://flathub.org/apps/details/com.itextpdf.RUPS
```

Comment: Note that if the user wants to force a new line, they can use double spaces + new line instead.

Comment: That backslash is not part of the markdown spec (as far as such a thing exists), so not all parsers will parse that as such... It's unfortunate the preview and actually parsed outputs don't match up though...